# Как в 1С в форме занести в Объект реквизиты?

Tags: 1с

Как в 1С в форме занести в Объект реквизиты? Чтобы реквизиты были подразделами Объект. Пробовал перетаскивать новые реквизиты, без результата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Создать реквизиты **в самом объекте**, как бы глупо это ни звучало.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]